# How match all possible numbers in a javascript expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've seen a lot of regex's matching numbers but none of them quite capture all valid numbers.

For example, I need to match all of the following:

```
//All of these can be preceded/followed by any of: +=-()!~%$#^&*{}[]|\;<>,
23
-23
4.8
1.3e-8
1.38e+5
-1.3e-2
-1.4e+2
```

but NOT match the following:

```
w23
-23w
_4.8 //This would see 8 as a number but not _4.
4yes
1.3ed-8 //This would see 1 and -8 as numbers but not .3ed
12dog
12foo
```

Is there a way to do such a regex?

Comment: Because the 3 is touching a word "ed" so it's not a valid number and the dot separates them.

Comment: 12d
12f are not valid numbers in JavaScript

Comment: You say "JavaScript expression", but you mean string. Expressions are something different.

Comment: Hmmm, You're right. I'll remove them (12d/f) from my example.

Comment: so you can't you just use `parseFloat()`?

Comment: @mykhal no, unfortnately I can't. I need a regex because I'm searching through strings trying to find the numbers. I just want to match the numbers in the strings I'm passed.

Comment: Here's what I have so far: `(?:^|[^\\w])+[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` but the problem is, it allows 56w to be a number which it is not.

Comment: For `_4.8`, why not match the `4.8`? Similarly, why 1 and 8 in `1.3ed8` and not 1.3 and 8? Do you really need to reject `12dog`, or just extract the `12` and leave `dog` behind?

Comment: So you are trying to match "valid" numbers randomly placed in a string.

Comment: Cameron: the reason is that if the expression/string `_4.8` were evaluated, it would cause an error. `_4` is not a valid number. And in the expression `1.3ed-8` (you missed the minus :) ) the `.3ed` is not a valid number and would cause an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find your requirements a bit bizarre, but this regex does what you want for all your examples:

```
-?\b\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][-+]?\d+)?\b
```

The key to making it fit your specification is to use the `\b` word boundary match.

Results for each:

```
23:
  23
-23:
  -23
4.8:
  4.8
1.3e-8:
  1.3e-8
1.38e+5:
  1.38e+5
-1.3e-2:
  -1.3e-2
-1.4e+2:
  -1.4e+2
w23:
-23w:
_4.8:
  8
4yes:
1.3ed-8:
  1
  -8
12dog:
12foo:
```

Comment: You managed a shorter regex than I did, that also fit the small numbers in the invalid numbers - nicely done. +1

Comment: This doesn't match `42e-1` which is a valid number. Instead it's matching only -1 in that string.

Comment: @Don: I've amended it to allow exponentials without decimals

Comment: Is this correct? `-?\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\\d+)?\\b`

Comment: @Don: That looks correct, I'll include the amendments into answer (allow no sign in exponentials and E to be any case).

Comment: Yep, just amend it to allow capital "E" as well and that's the answer! Thanks so much for your (and everyone's) help!

Answer (score 2):

If you use the following regex with the `m` flag (`^` and `$` match the beginning and end of each new line), it will return valid for all of your supplied valid numbers, and invalid for the supplied invalid numbers:

```
^[+=\-()!~%$#\^&*{}[\]|\\;<>,]*\d+[\.\d]*([a-zA-Z][\+\-]\d+)?[+=\-()!~%$#\^&*{}[\]|\\;<>,]*$
```

Broken down:

```
^                                   #start of string (line, with "m" flag)
  [+=\-()!~%$#\^&*{}[\]|\\;<>,]*    #zero or more of any of these characters.
  \d+                               #one or more digits (basic number: 123)
  [\.\d]*                           #zero or more periods or digits (to account for floats: 1.11)
  ([a-zA-Z][\+\-]\d+)?              #one or zero instance of a letter, a + or - sign, then 1 or more digits (to account for scientific notation floats: 1.23e+3 or 1.23e-3)
  [+=\-()!~%$#\^&*{}[\]|\\;<>,]*    #once again, zero or more of any of these characters.
$                                   #end of string (line, with "m" flag)
```

Comment: Hmmm, this doesn't work for me as it's matching "w13" as a number.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the entire regex? I'm testing it using http://regexpal.com/, and it's working just fine for me.

Comment: you're right! Sorry about that. There is one thing that needs to be changed though. instead of [a-zA-Z] it needs to just be [eE] as that's the only valid letter in there. Also, does this give the same results (adapted from @Porges): `-?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?\b` I like it simply because it's shorter.

Comment: His regex will capture the two sub-numbers out of the invalid numbers, so personally I'd choose that one - he did a good job on it.